# What events to handle in DataGridView for inline update / add / delete?

Tags: c#, .net

Essentially I want the user experience to be that they can go into the DGV and edit the data (ie click a cell, type some stuff, hit enter), and have it immediately go to the database.  I can handle the SQL side, but what events should I handle so I can figure out if the user has done an add, delete, or update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string LastCellText; TextBox Textbox;
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Control is TextBox)
        {
            Textbox = e.Control as TextBox;
            Textbox.TextChanged += Textbox_TextChanged;
        }
    }

    void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Your actions 
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Textbox.Text ==string .Empty )
        {
            //Do Delete
        }
        if (Textbox.Text !=  LastCellText)
        {
           //If Textbox.Text is in the database do Update else do ADD
        }
      LastCellText=Textbox.Text;
      Textbox.TextChanged -= Textbox_TextChanged;
    }
```